# how does fibonacci with recursion works

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

```
int fib(int i) {
    if(i<2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return fib(i-1) + fib(i-2) ;
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand how the statements  return `fib(i-1) + fib(i-2)` is processed???

Does `fib(i-1)` is process first and `fib(i-2)` or both get processed simultaneously??

Also, suppose `fib(i-1)=3`, then in this case how `fib(i-1)=3` gets calculated..i know that this further get called to `fib(i-1)=2` and `fib(i-1)=1` which give `1` as return in both cases. Then how does `fib(i-1)=3` gets calculated based on `fib(i-1)=2` and `fib(i-1)=1`???

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
fib(4) = 
fib(3) + fib(2) = 
fib(2) + fib(1) + fib(2) = 
fib(1) + fib(0) + fib(1) + fib(2) = 
1 + fib(0) + fib(1) + fib(2) = 
1 + 1 + fib(1) + fib(2) = 
2 + fib(1) + fib(2) = 
2 + 1 + fib(2) = 
3 + fib(2) = 
3 + fib(1) + fib(0) = 
3 + 1 + fib(0) = 
4 + fib(0) = 
4 + 1 = 
5
```

Nothing gets exectued "simultaneously", it just calls `fib` multiple times in itself while evaluting your first call of `fib(4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time it runs into the statement `return fib(i-1) + fib(i-2) ;`, it must find out what `fib(i-1)` is first and then what `fib(i-2)` is each time. Every time where i does not fulfill the requirement of being less than 2, it must go to an instance of `return fib(i-1) + fib(i-2) ;`. It then looks first for what that `fib(i-1)` is and then what that `fib(i-2)` is. If `fib(i-1)` is what caused it to go to another instance of the else statement, then that means it will be looking for the second `fib(i-1)` and then the second `fib(i-2)` before looking for the first `fib(i-2)` since those second parts are needed to determine what the first `fib(i-1)` is. It will continue to go deeper and further with the else statement as long as it does not meet the if statements requirements. Once, it has its first 1 from the if statement, it will then be able to start filling in all the values for the `fib(i-1)`s and `fib(i-2)`s it previously ran into until it gets back to the first `fib(i-1)`. Only then can it move on to the first `fib(i-2)` and go down as it needs to there to enter the if statment before entering in those 1s and adding them up to find just what the first `return fib(i-1) + fib(i-2) ;` is. If this only makes things more confusing, I would recommend writing it out with arrows pointing to show the steps being taken so you know where you are and what all has been done more clearly. Doing that helped me out when first learning recursion with Fibonacci.

Answer (score -1):

```
fib(4) =                fib(3)                +                   fib(2)

                fib(2)        +       fib(1)     +           fib(1)    +     fib(0)

            fib(1) + fib(0)   +         1        +             1       +       1

              1   +   1       +         1        +             1       +       1     =    5
```